# Laravel 5.5: Supervisor Does Not Run All Tasks In Queue

Tags: laravel, supervisord

This is really weird.

My program will dispatch one QuoteCommitSavedListener job and this job will trigger two QuoteCommitNotification jobs. (These two job both implement ShouldQueue interface.)

When I run this command in shell

```
php /home/nginx/test/artisan queue:work redis --queue=default --tries=3
```

It will display as follow. It's so fine.

```
[2018-04-04 07:25:17] Processing: App\Listeners\QuoteCommitSavedListener
[2018-04-04 07:25:18] Processed:  App\Listeners\QuoteCommitSavedListener
[2018-04-04 07:25:18] Processing: App\Notifications\QuoteCommitNotification
[2018-04-04 07:25:22] Processed:  App\Notifications\QuoteCommitNotification
[2018-04-04 07:25:22] Processing: App\Notifications\QuoteCommitNotification
[2018-04-04 07:25:26] Processed:  App\Notifications\QuoteCommitNotification
```

There are one QuoteCommitSavedListener job and two QuoteCommitNotification jobs.

But when I run the queue by supervisor, it will display

```
[2018-04-04 07:30:43] Processing: App\Listeners\QuoteCommitSavedListener
[2018-04-04 07:30:43] Processed:  App\Listeners\QuoteCommitSavedListener
[2018-04-04 07:30:43] Processing: App\Notifications\QuoteCommitNotification
[2018-04-04 07:30:48] Processed:  App\Notifications\QuoteCommitNotification
```

I do not know why the second QuoteCommitNotification job disappeared.

This is my supervisor config

```
[program:test-queue]
command=php /home/nginx/test/artisan queue:work redis --queue=default --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/nginx/test/storage/logs/queue-default.log
```

Comment: run `supervisorctl reread && supervisorctl reload`, check if the result the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is two laravel application share a same redis database. Change one's config to solve this problem.